# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> ## N.B.
>
> The size requirements for adverts have changed. It is **NOT** appropriate to simply copy over the images from previous years - they won't work. Images need to be **300×250px** or 600×500px for retina displays, up from 220×250px in previous years. If an image is taller than it is wide, it's the wrong size.

---

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7426).

Comment: When do the new ads go live?

Comment: Also: can someone fill me in with *why* they're downvoting this post? I just don't see what the rationale is here and would like to understand.

Comment: @Emilio We're delaying the activation some bit to allow for sites that have lots of ads from the old width but haven't updated the widths to match yet. We're probably looking at some time February for that, but if we see a lot of ads being submitted at the new width then we'll push it sooner.

Comment: @GraceNote Is there any update on the go-live date on the new ads? To me it looks like we are ready (as are e.g. math and academia). Or is the roll-out a single network-wide go?

Comment: Just heard that ads can be up to 150KB: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273200/community-ads-filesize-cannot-exceed-40kb-difficult-with-new-bigger-ads-hig/273271#273271

Answer (score 26):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: Edited version of [the 2014 ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/posts/5266/revisions). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016%202.svg).

Answer (score 23):

[image: Physics Stack Exchange Review Queue]

Comment: Looking at it now, I think I might want to add a black border to it, but not sure at the moment. FWIW, that's the [Comfortaa font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Comfortaa) from Google.

Comment: I set the green background throughout, looks better IMO. [SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/reviews%20ad%202016.svg), png compressed with pngcrush.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Earliest Detexify I know of](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013/11616#11616), re-jigged into the new specs and with some extra oomph to use the added space. [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/detexify%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 15):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/hsm%20ad%202016.svg), working off of [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Diophantus_title_I_1621.jpg).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: [Zipped source - Inkscape SVG and Mathematica notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/dlmf%20ad.zip)

Comment: The design follows the print companion ([NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521192255)) rather than the DLMF itself, because the companion has nice design and the DLMF... well, the companion has nice design. If you've never gone there, click the link. Seriously, the DLMF is awesome.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Community ads are decided by the community. Come and vote!]

Comment: Re-jig of [this 2014 ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5571/8563). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/community%20ads%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scicomp%20ad%202016.svg). Offended programmers please apply to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Comment: cross-ref: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2712/4945

Answer (score 12):

[image: Discover our universe]

Comment: Enlarged the image after hearing about the new file size limit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273200/community-ads-filesize-cannot-exceed-40kb-difficult-with-new-bigger-ads-hig/273271#273271

Comment: That's no moon... it's a space station.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Design elements shamelessly stolen from [academia.se]. [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/academia%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 11):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: [First arXiv Analytics ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6127/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arxiv%20analytics%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: Thanks! I upload your Inkscape SVG source on dropbox to my website as the filename `arxiv-analytics-ad-2016-by-Emilio-Pisanty.svg`: http://oss.arxitics.com/images/arxiv-analytics-ad-2016-by-Emilio-Pisanty.svg When I use this file someday, I will provide the attribution. Is it appropriate?

Comment: @soliton Go ahead and use the file for advertising as you see fit. If you do provide it within a broader context (which you may well want to, such as Zotero's branding page) then you can attribute it there.

Comment: [Relevant discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37517/discussion-between-emilio-pisanty-and-soliton).

Comment: When we have noticed a server down, we will try our best to recover it as soon as we can. Please come back later. If you cannot connect to the site due to some reasons, please contact us at help@arxitics.com Thanks! @MartinUeding

Answer (score 11):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Comment: Copied from [this Mathematics ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22436/30935).

Answer (score 11):

[image: physics chat]

Comment: Are you sure the size is right?

Comment: I don't think it will stop it displaying but this needs a 1px non-white border.

Comment: I don't see the chat event scheduled, though (i.e. the link is essentially empty at present). The chat event should also turn up on the sticky yellow thing at top right of the homepage when it gets scheduled.

Comment: hi all for those not aware we had a long conversation on this topic in the physics chat room recently re coordination etc., see transcript; mod David Z has graciously agreed to allow the current recurring chat mtg for a special guest on special occasions & put link on home pg after arranged. DS has not yet committed to a mtg time/ date, we want to build up interest/ attn (asking for help on that from everyone) eg with this _approved_ ad & otherwise. plz direct further questions/ coordination  to me in chat room eg chat ping me, will respond there. we also need volunteers for the speaker! :)

Comment: In that case the advert as posed will act negatively in that regard. Once the advert goes live it needs to click through to somewhere that actually describes what you're talking about (instead of the current schedule for the generic chat meeting). If for whatever reason you can't / don't want to schedule a specific chat event, then you should make a new thread on meta explaining the idea, with a (*maintained*) answer with the current schedule (including dates as TBD if necessary).

Comment: Also, vague references to "see transcript" are essentially useless. If you want to reference chat, do it properly and link to the appropriate part of the transcript incl. date & time.

Comment: Another point - if you want this to be anything like a sustainable series (beginning with having more than one of them) then you need to get your chops up on recruiting speakers. That starts with describing what would be required of them and what 'AMA' is to a general (non-reddit-aware) audience. If you're looking for speakers you need to be proactive about it.

Comment: @Emilio you seem to have a lot of ideas how to pull this off. dont think this ad comment section is the place to discuss it. plz ping me in chat & will answer your objections there

Comment: @vzn Nah, not really. Just saying: if you don't do this properly, even this ad as currently posed is not really appropriate.

Comment: @Emilio not appreciating your 1sided words/ resistance/ critique on "how to do this properly" or what is an "appropriate ad" & no response in the chat room. there was a lot of discussion/ coordination already in the site chat room with the 1st guest and site mod DZ & its easy to find with search. _the guest speaker concept is DZs idea in a site chat mtg etc_ :(

Comment: Sorry for being brusque - don't really have the time. I'd like to see this go forward but cannot at present contribute. Just don't put a live ad that links to an empty location (as it is at present).

Comment: you do have the time to challenge it openly, but apparently not to help push it fwd. :( _its not an "empty location"_. we cant get new ads approved for every guest, its unrealistic/ difficult, so both DS/ DZ suggested/ are ok with a generic ad. the ad cant point to a guest that has agreed in principle but hasnt committed to a time yet. the current ad doubles as pointing to the chat room/ recurring mtg, and announcing a guest speaker plan. the ad can be easily revised with a new link & same graphics when possible.

Comment: @vzn Emilio isn't give you objections, he's giving you very, very good *advice*.

Comment: Cool idea, but do it right! I can't get much info from your link.

Comment: @innisfree I believe the link is considerably more useful now :D

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think the link is much improved now.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed it is. I'm pretty sure that that was the cause of the downvotes - hopefully people will reconsider.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, perhaps, although I don't know how often people check over their down-voted items to look for improvements.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes. Which is why I insisted on this from the start. There's still time, though, and only three votes to get this live.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Comment: Re-jig of the [2014 ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6505/8563), posted to [their meta](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174/community-ads-to-use-in-other-sites) in case they come up with something prettier. [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/engineering%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: Slightly oversized, limit is 150KB and this is 158KB. Could you notch it down?

Comment: I'll look into it. This one is surprisingly hard to downsize on Inkscape for some reason.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Run it through GIMP, and set PNG compression to 9. It's lossless, I believe.

Comment: @wizz The ad is currently running, I think, so there's probably no need to change it for now.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Wayback Machine: experience the Web as it was]

Answer (score 10):

[image: archive.org - the public library of the internet]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/internet%20archive%20ad%202016.svg); requires the fonts Iconochive and Agfa Rotis Semi Serif. Comments on the design welcome.

Comment: +1; thumbs up; done a splendid job.

Answer (score 9):

[image: For those seeking down-to-earth answers to their questions]

Comment: I'm for this but I'm not amazingly keen on the image - there's probably a better image of the globe to be had.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Edited.

Comment: Yeah, much better.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Comment: Adapted from the [2014 Academia thread](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1483/820). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/retraction%20watch%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 8):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Edited form of the [earliest SciRate ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5982/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scirate%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: I think less text might be better because as is the text is heard to parse visually. Perhaps something like *"Vote and comment on arxiv preprints"*

Answer (score 8):

[image: Digital Open Access Identifier - a DOI resolver that prioritizes open access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/doai%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: Well, that was an embarrassing typo...

Answer (score 8):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: Can we switch the caption to *free*  mathematical software rather than plain open-source? Or at least write something like free/open-source?

Answer (score 7):

[image: physicsoverflow.org]

Comment: Due to prior experience, we're asking everyone to avoid discussion in the comment section here. Instead, use the [related meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451) and [its chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17799).

Answer (score 6):

[image: cryptography.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Copied from [this community promotion ad](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2162/17534) on Academia.SE. I think this might interest a few here. (Those who disagree can obviously down-vote this!)

Comment: Reposted on the [2017 Community Promotion Ads](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9588/121464) thread.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Current Physics Stack Exchange bounties]

Answer (score 5):

[image: The Cost of Knowledge - join the Elsevier boycott and take back our scientific publishing!]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/the%20cost%20of%20knowledge%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: This is maybe not quite an awesome fit for this site, but I thought I'd float the idea here.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Comment: [Inkskape source SVG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/zotero%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: "This proposal has been deleted."

Comment: @unor Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: So what is different about this proposal compared to whatever made the previous one fold? To be honest (on a devil's-advocate, more-harsh-than-I-actually-think sort of way), this just looks like a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: [The chat room dedicated to this proposal](http://goo.gl/VxYdsL)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Are your papers available in an open access repository? Check with Dissemin]

Comment: Copied from [the 2016 Academia thread](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2164).

Answer (score 0):

[image: A community on a mission to solve all STEM]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs]

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see the case here - we already have MathJax enabled on site. In any case, it would be better to have a more descriptive ad (i.e. specifically for the Auto-LaTeX Chrome add-on, rather than something that looks like a misleadingly generic LaTeX ad and turns out not to be.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Well the Google docs logo is fairly wellknown, so I thought that would imply that the latex is for Google docs, hence the addon

Answer (score -3):

[image: arXiv.org - over a million papers, free to access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score -7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Once again the annual "downvote Grace Note's demo twitter ad" tradition begins ;)

Comment: Well, we should really check on the Twitter account each year and see whether its posts are things we want to promote.