# Please don't stretch the old community ads!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

So the sidebar got [stretched by about 30%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). No problem. This entails a change to the network-provided ads (not visible above certain rep thresholds) and to the community ads. No problem. Some old ads [ran with some extra whitespace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884976_272563) while they were updated. No problem. We need to [update all our community ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884977_272563) [to the new size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment885010_272563). Grumble, but no problem, it's a good opportunity to spiff up the graphics on some of them. The community ads thread got delayed a bit this year. Absolutely fine. We [don't really know when the 2016 ads kick in](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/community-promotion-ads-2016#comment29266_7426). Not awesome on the lack of clarity, but not a problem as long as nothing terrible comes of it.

This is a problem, though:

[image]

This ad is currently running and it comes from [the 2015 thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388#6399). For comparison, here is that advert as posted:

[image]

### If you're going to run 2015 community ads in the expanded sidebar, pad them out with whitespace instead of stretching them.

Quite simple, really.

---

This question [first posted on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads). Re-posted here as a signpost as it affects this site; give the MSE question some love if you agree with it.

Answer (score 2):

So this has been resolved over on the mother meta. Quoting from a member of the SE team:

> Looks like we jumped the gun on a sidebar change for community ads.
>   Sorry about that.
>
> The change has been reverted, and the updated build is rolling out
>   into production as I type this.

Comment: Okay, while checking through the site, I got this stretched ad of Chem SE:http://i.stack.imgur.com/GSOdg.png ; isn't the issue solved? There were ads of 220x250 px lately; why were thy stretched then? The sooner they resolve it completely, the better.

Comment: Yeah, the issue appears to be intermittent - I saw a stretched ad on math.se earlier today.